# How do you get a millisecond-precision unix timestamp in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, timestamp

What is the Haskell equivalent of this shell command?

```
$ date "+%s%3N"
1489694389603
```

Answer (score 20):

Using the [time](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) package:

1. Use `getPOSIXTime`, which returns a [`NominalDiffTime`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.5/time-1.6.0.1/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:NominalDiffTime). This represents a *fractional* number of seconds, with a precision of 10<sup>-12</sup> seconds.
2. Multiply 1000 to convert from seconds to milliseconds.
3. `NominalDiffTime` implements the [`RealFrac`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.5/base-4.9.1.0/Prelude.html#t:RealFrac) class, so you can use `round` to convert to an integer.

---

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX (getPOSIXTime)

λ> (round . (* 1000)) <$> getPOSIXTime
1489694668011
```